# New to Programming -- Java Window not displaying

Tags: java

Just a quick run down of my code, this java application is to create a window with **3 buttons**:

- OFF
- 2.5V
- 5.0V

The buttons are to communicate with my **Arduino Uno**. 
Right now, I've fixed the errors and no errors are being displayed on NetBeans.
 However, the window with the buttons is not showing up, can someone check my code, please?
 Thanks.

```
package javaapplication1;

import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
//import java.awt.BorderLayout;
//import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
//import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUItest extends JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener, WindowListener, MouseListener {
    public static void main(String[] argv){
}
    private JFrame  mainWindow;
    //private JPanel  mainPanel;
    private JButton degrees0OFF;
    private JButton degrees0HALF;
    private JButton degrees0ON;

    SerialPort serialPort;
    private InputStream serialIn;
    private OutputStream serialOut;
    private BufferedReader serialReader;

    public GUItest() {
        super("RCDA Senior Design"); //Title of the window
        //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        mainWindow = new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setSize(600, 600);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

        degrees0OFF = new JButton("OFF"); //name of the button
        degrees0HALF = new JButton("2.5V"); //name of the button
        degrees0ON = new JButton("5.0V"); //name of the button

        mainWindow.add(degrees0OFF);
        mainWindow.add(degrees0HALF);
        mainWindow.add(degrees0ON);
        degrees0OFF.addMouseListener(this);
        degrees0HALF.addMouseListener(this);
        degrees0ON.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void begin() throws Exception{
        //this.setVisible(true);

    // Open port
    CommPortIdentifier port = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM8"); 
        CommPort commPort = port.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);
        serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    serialIn=serialPort.getInputStream();
    serialOut=serialPort.getOutputStream();
    serialReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(serialIn) );
        //serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent e) {
        Log.debug("serialEvent: "+e.toString());
        try {
                    String line = serialReader.readLine();
                    Log.debug("READ from serial: "+line);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        @Override public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)       {}
    @Override public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)       {}
    @Override public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e)    {}
    @Override public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e)  {}
    @Override public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)    {}
    @Override public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)  {}
    @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)      {
        Log.debug("windowClosing: "+e);
        if(e.getComponent()==this){
            Log.debug("Closing port");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
        @Override       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  {}
    @Override   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)  {}
    @Override   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)  {}
    @Override   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)   {}
    @Override   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        Log.debug("mouseReleased: "+e);

        if(e.getComponent() == degrees0OFF){  //degrees0OFF
            Log.debug("OFF button released");
            try {
                serialOut.write("B1".getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(e.getComponent() == degrees0HALF){  //degrees0HALF
            Log.debug("2.5V button released");
            try {
                serialOut.write("B2".getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
                if(e.getComponent() == degrees0ON){  //degrees0ON
            Log.debug("5.0V button released");
            try {
                serialOut.write("B3".getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your main method does nothing

Answer (score 0):

As your `GUITest` class already extends `JFrame`, you do not have to create a new object inside of it.

I'd recommend you to edit the `main` method into your class with this only instruction :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    GUITest myFrame = new GUITest();
}
```

And inside your code refer to your object using the `this` keyword.

---

Also, the `setVisible(boolean)` is usually used at the end of all instructions to make sure everything has been done before your `Frame` is visible

Answer (score 0):

Your main method does not do anything, thus nothing will happen.

You need to instantiate and display your JFrame.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUITest window = new GUITest();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```